CASTEP: specification of uniform pressure in a non-orthogonal unit cell?
I want to get confirmation as to the correct way to specify a uniform isotropic EXTERNAL_PRESSURE for geometry optimization in a non-orthogonal unit cell using the academic CASTEP code (i.e. not using the Materials Studio interface, but rather in the generated input files).
I have a unit cell with:
a b c 8.24600 4.79900 9.19601

alpha beta gamma 90.0000 63.0282 90.0000

and I have mapped the cell to:

%BLOCK LATTICE_CART

0.0 8.24600 0.0

0.0 0.0 4.79900

8.1957587287 4.1708678686 0.0

%ENDBLOCK LATTICE_CART

The CASTEP documentation describes the EXTERNAL_PRESSURE block in terms of Rxx,Rxy, etc. which sounds like orthogonal Cartesians, so I am wondering: if I want to impose an isotropic external pressure of 'P' GPa, what would the EXTERNAL_PRESSURE block need to look like?

For an isotropic (hydrostatic) pressure, you would expect that to give you a diagonal matrix, so:
%Block External_Pressure 

1 0 0 

0 1 0 

0 0 1 

%endblock External_Pressure

(apologies for the poor formatting - I can't figure out how to put in a new line without a paragraph space!)
Of course, you could also have a non-diagonal matrix that is isotropic, the important thing is that the matrix has 3 degenerate eigenvalues. Needless to say, the easiest way to construct a matrix with 3 degenerate eigenvalues is simply to construct a matrix that is diagonal to begin with!
Hope that helps,
Rob

Thank you Rob, that matches what I've learned from the devs.

I have received the following answer direct from some of the CASTEP developer group.
' .. external pressure is always specified in Cartesians regardless of cell geometry. Hence hydrostatic P would be
%block external_pressure
GPA
P 0 0
    P 0
        P
%endblock external_pressure

'
The important point here is that it doesn't matter what the geometry of the unit cell is (i.e. it can have cell angles that are NOT 90 degrees). The external pressure is ALWAYS specified in orthogonal Cartesian coordinates.
